# compare moment date in angular

Tags: angular, momentjs

I'm trying to compare days between two moments to see if the difference for number of days between end_date_moment and start_date_moment is > 15.

```
differenceNumberOfday(endtimestamp, starttimestamp){
   const start = moment(endtimestamp).valueOf();
   const end = moment(starttimestamp).valueOf();
}
```

My attempt:

```
differenceNumberOfday(endtimestamp, starttimestamp){
   const start = moment(endtimestamp).valueOf();
   const end = moment(starttimestamp).valueOf();
   if(moment(endtimestamp).getDay() - moment(startimestamp).getDay() >15){
   }else{}
}
```

In the above attempt, the getDay() does not return the correct day. Is there something im missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `diff` to solve this (Source: [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/))

Here is a working example.

```js
function differenceNumberOfday(endtimestamp, starttimestamp){
    const start = moment(starttimestamp);
    const end = moment(endtimestamp);
    if (end.diff(start, 'days') > 15) {
        console.log('more than 15 days');
    } else {
        console.log('not more than 15 days')
    }
}

console.log('Aug 6 2019 - Aug 21 2019');
differenceNumberOfday("2019-08-21T00:00:00", "2019-08-06T00:00:00");
console.log('Aug 5 2019 - Aug 21 2019');
differenceNumberOfday("2019-08-21T00:00:00", "2019-08-05T00:00:00");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the timestamp is in this format actually 2019-08-06T00:00:00

Comment: This works with this format as well. Check the updated answer.